# What is the significant difference with parenthesis when using function parameters

Tags: scala

I was recently playing with a piece of code which relies heavily on function parameters and noticed the following behaviour which I can't quite explain to myself:

```
// first, a few methods
def a(x: => Any) {}
def b(x:() => Any) {}
// then some helpers
def x = {}
def y() = {}
// these execute the possible combinations
a(x)
b(y)
a(y)
b(x)
```

The first three work as expected, but the fourth one fails. REPL output for it is

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: () => Any
              b(x)
                ^
```

For me `x` and `y` look the same but they obviously aren't. At first I thought it was some kind of property access instead of method being referenced but I couldn't reason that through since `a(y)` seems to work just fine - in other words, I can't see the symmetry between the operations.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate or not, I do have to say that Patrik's answer is lighter on the reader than the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are quite different and as usual (annoying, I know) the compiler is right.

`def a(x: => Any)` - Function that takes a parameter `x` **by name** where `x` is `Any` and returns unit, so the full definition would be: `def a(x: => Any) : Unit`.

`def b(x: () => Any)` - Function that takes a parameter `x` **by value**, where `x` is a function `() => Any`.

`def x = {}` is equivalent to `def x : Unit = {}`

`def y() = {}` is equivalent to `def y(): Unit = {}` (Which is a function mapping no parameters, i.e. `()`, to `Unit`, i.e. `Any`).

So, the fourth one fails, since `x` is not a function mapping no parameters to `Any`, it is just a property returning `Unit`.